# How to generate proper bitmaps for the Font?

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, fonts, bitmap

I have a question concerning Bitmap fonts. I need to create fonts for screen device. It should consists of bitmaps of all printable characters. To get a bitmaps of all characters I am using the following approach:

```
public MFont(Font font, int first = 32, int last = 126)
{        
    var characters = new List<Character>();
    Bitmap objBmpImage = new Bitmap(1, 1);

    // Create a graphics object to measure the text's width and height.
    Graphics objGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(objBmpImage);

    for (int i = first; i <= last; i++)
    {
        char c = Convert.ToChar(i);
        int intWidth;
        int intHeight;
        string s = "" + c;

        // This is where the bitmap size is determined.                
        intWidth = (int)objGraphics.MeasureString(s, font).Width;
        intHeight = (int)objGraphics.MeasureString(s, font).Height;

        // Create the bmpImage again with the correct size for the text and font.
        objBmpImage = new Bitmap(objBmpImage, new Size(intWidth, intHeight));    

        objGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(objBmpImage);    
        // Set Background color
        objGraphics.Clear(Color.White);
        objGraphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.None;
        objGraphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixelGridFit;
        objGraphics.DrawString(s, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 0, 0);           
        objGraphics.Flush();                  

        characters.Add(
            new Character
                {
                    Bitmap = objBmpImage,
                    Code = i,
                    Size = objBmpImage.Size                        

                }
            );
    }
}
```

The problem is that all character bitmaps have too many space on both left and right sides. So, when I display text using thees bitmaps on the screen, the text is like after each character a space was added. How can I repair that? Maybe there is something I am not aware about fonts, or how they should be displayed. I know that I can crop bitmaps manually, but this is not very accurate and clear. Besides that some characters don't have any redundant space at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That extra space on either sides are the padding.  You have to specify NoPadding on the flags.  Read the following link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc751527.aspx

Also, beware that the string measurement may take into consideration the space needed for italics text -- so you may have extra spacing on the right of each character.

You say that some characters don't have redundant spaces.  Which means that the extra spacing you see is can be due to kerning, or the lack thereof.

You have to implement you own "kerning" to pack the characters tight (for proportional fonts).  Otherwise, you're always going to look sub-optimal.

There are ways to fudge kerning, but it requires you to do some post processing on your bitmaps.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `TextRenderer.MeasureText()` instead of `Graphics.MeasureString()`. It allows you to specify the `TextFormatFlags` that will be used during measurement. I suspect that padding is added by default, so try passing `TextFormatFlags.NoPadding` to the method and see if your results change.

Comment: Strangely, but TextRenderer.MeasureText() with TextFormatFlags.NoPadding gives even more Width.